# Qemu build failing with “fatal error: scsi/sg.h: No such file or directory”

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

Trying to build Qemu from source to run kvm. I am following the instructions from https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Linux. This resulting following error message.

> block/file-posix.c:67:21: fatal error: scsi/sg.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>
> CC      block/nbd-client.o
>
> qemu/rules.mak:69: recipe for target 'block/file-posix.o' failed

I can locate the header file in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-41/include/scsi/sg.h. What could be the reason of failure.

Comment: AFAIK it should be in /usr/include - provided by libc6-dev

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver . Reinstalling libc6-dev did not put appropriate header in /usr/include. What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: It's 16.04.1-Ubuntu with 4.13.0-41-generic kernel.

Comment: In that case I don't understand why it's not there - https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libc6-dev/filelist

Comment: Installing the debian package(libc6-dev_2.23-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb) resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Installing the packages with dpkg as per the last comment fixed the issue for me too. @Proy I think you should turn that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apt to start at the way it is usually built for packaging.
The error you mention seems just like missing dependencies, which you'd automatically pull in via

```
apt-get build-dep qemu
```

One has to realize that this is for the config that the Distribution builds qemu. So you might either get the source as used by the Distro and check debian/rules what is done.

```
# for Xenial it will be 2.5
apt install dpkg-dev
apt-get source qemu
vim qemu-2.5+dfsg/debian/rules
```

Or you can check any release build log (and thereby effective configure call) from [qemu package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu) to e.g. the [build log of xenial](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/371562377/buildlog_ubuntu-xenial-amd64.qemu_1%3A2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.30_BUILDING.txt.gz)
To do so click on the version you want, then the architetcture you are interested and then on "buildlog".

From there you can start to derive/modify as you need it.